# set rgba color of points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to the docs this is supposed to work. It does not. I must be misreading the docs. Anybody have the fix?

```
from pylab import *
N = 100
x = randn(N)
y = randn(N)
c = rand(N, 4)
plot(x, y, 'o', c=c)
```

Error in IPython notebook (python3):

```
lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ 0.29844256  0.96853857  0.75812229  0.22794978]
 [ 0.81606887  0.31641358  0.53254456  0.44198844]
 [ 0.06961026  0.3265891   0.03006253  0.00485412]
 [ 0.32580911  0.86645991  0.04140443  0.35550554]
```

Error in plain IPython (python3):

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ -2.78401664e-01  -8.33924015e-01   7.54508871e-01]
 [ -3.02839674e-01  -1.18292516e+00  -7.71274654e-01]
 [ -3.58099013e-01  -1.18899472e+00   1.39868995e+00]
```

Docs:

```
help(plot)

....

In addition, you can specify colors in many weird and
wonderful ways, including full names (``'green'``), hex
strings (``'#008000'``), RGB or RGBA tuples (``(0,1,0,1)``) or
grayscale intensities as a string (``'0.8'``).  Of these, the
string specifications can be used in place of a ``fmt`` group,
but the tuple forms can be used only as ``kwargs``.
```

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive than *"does not [work]"*? What happens, and what were you expecting instead? Could you give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including imports, etc.? And could you provide a source for the docs?

Comment: Added the error message. I assume I am reading the docs incorrectly but I was surprised to not find something about this in a a few tired google searches.

Comment: And the other things?

Comment: I think this is more about the docs than the code but I've added more to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you want points with multiple different colors?

If so, use `scatter`, rather than plot. (That's basically the difference between the two. `plot` is more efficient, but limited to one size/color for all points.)

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
c = np.random.random((N, 4))

plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your call to `rand` (`numpy.random.rand`) returns a numpy ndarray:

> numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)
>   Random values in a given shape.
>
> Create an array of the given shape and propagate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).
>
> Parameters :
>   d0, d1, ..., dn : int, optional
>
> The dimensions of the returned array, should all be positive. If no argument is given a single Python float is returned.
>
> **Returns :**
>   **out : ndarray, shape (d0, d1, ..., dn)**
>
> Random values.

The matplotlib `color` argument needs to adhere to one of the formats listed. Specifically, you want to pass an RGBA python tuple.

Try something more like this:

```
color = tuple(numpy.random.rand(4)) # 4 random vals between 0.0-1.0
```

Comment: This answer actually helped me solve my problem with a similar error message. Thanks